# Tabs missing in Unity Dash

Tags: unity, 13.10, unity-dash

After my friend having accidentally aborted the update to Ubuntu 13.10, several tabs in the Unity Dash are missing. Is there any package I can install to get them back?

[image: dash]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get purge unity
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Answer (score 0):

Running these:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop-2d
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install xserver-xgl
sudo apt-get install emerald
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install git compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install unity
```

and rebooting should solve it, as it should put the extra bits back in.